# 80’s/90’s fantasy book where men travelled across the land and inhabited creatures such as deer, beavers and pixies

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't have a great deal of info on what I'm looking for. I read a book when I was younger, probably written in the 80’s or early 90’s.

It was about these 2 people (male I think) that were traveling across a land to get somewhere, they would have to become the creatures that inhabited that area to get across it. They were deer once, beaver, one was a pixie once, there were other creatures.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could this be Jack Chalker's "Midnight at the Well of Souls"? The first of a series of books all set on a planet called the Well World. Science Fiction rather than Fantasy, but with a lot of similar elements.

1. Two people traveling across a world covered by thousands of hex-shaped
   zones, each populated with different races of creatures. However the
   main characters are a man and a women not two men. Nathan Brazil and
   Wu Julee. They are joined by others during the journey.
2. Characters changing shape to conform to the native popluations. When
   travelers are transported to the world they are sorted into hexes
   that need population. The people are transformed into the race of
   their assigned hex. Nathan stays a conventional looking human but Wu
   Julee is changed into a centaur.
3. A one point Nathan Brazil is changed to a deer after being injured
   crossing a hex.
4. There is a race called Ambreza that resemble giant beavers and
   inhabit the hex zone adjacent to the one that is home to
   conventional looking humans. No one becomes an Ambreza but there
   is interaction with characters.
5. There is a race called Lata that resemble flying pixies. One of the 
   characters from this book becomes a Lata in a later sequel "Quest
   for the Well of Souls".
6. There are many, many other creature races described in the book. The
   other main characters become a mermaid, a giant bat, a giant insect,
   a bi-pedal plant, and a six-armed walrus/snake.
7. Some of the races can use magic that might cause the book to be
   remembered as Fantasy.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something in the Well World series by Jack Chalker maybe?

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain how this matches and why it is correct?

Comment: I put this up before the other answer - but I had meant to comment rather than answer. The major explained it very well, and I don't mind in any case. I had just wanted to point people in the right direction so someone else could write up something more coherent. MajorMattMason's answer upvoted.